# liftability of isomorphism of curves in $P^3$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, fano-varieties

It is well known that the isomorphism between smooth curves $C$ and $C'$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ can be lifted to an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^2$ if degree of $C$ and $C'\geq 4$. Now I am considering an isomorphism $f:C\cong C'$ such that $C,C'\subset\mathbb{P}^3$. I know that in general such isomorphism is impossible to lift an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^3$. But in my case, $C,C'$ are in following special situation.

1. $S\in |\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(3)|$ is a smooth cubic surface, write $\pi:S\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^2$ the blow up of 6 general points and denote the exceptional divisor of $\pi$ by $E_1,\ldots,E_6$ and we choose $C,C'\in |\pi^*\mathcal{O}(4)-2E_1-E_2-\ldots-E_5|$ general. Then $C,C'$ are smooth curves of degree $6$ and genus $2$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$.
2. $S\in |\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(3)|$ is a smooth cubic surface, write $\pi:S\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^2$ the blow up of 6 general points and denote the exceptional divisor of $\pi$ by $E_1,\ldots,E_6$ and we choose $C.C'\in |\pi^*\mathcal{O}(8)-2E_1-2E_2-3E_3-\ldots-3E_6|$ general. Then $C,C'$ are smooth curves of degree $8$ and genus $7$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

**So my question** is if $f:C\cong C'$ is an isomorphism of two curves in the situation 1 and 2, whether $f$ can be lifted to an automorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb{P}^3$ such that $\phi|_C=f$.

By some reason, I would expect that $f$ can not be lifted in situation 1 but can be lifted in situation 2.

Another question is that if we have some literature studying this kind of questions, I did not find anything using Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An isomorphism $f \colon C \to C'$ of (linearly normal) projective curves lifts to an isomorphism of their ambient spaces if and only if
$$
f^*L' \cong L,\tag{*}
$$
where $L$ and $L'$ are the line bundles inducing the embeddings into the ambient projective spaces. For instance, if $C$ and $C'$ are plane curves of degree $d \ge 4$ then
$$
L \cong \omega_C^{d -3},
\qquad 
L' \cong \omega_{C'}^{d -3},
$$
so the isomorphism $(*)$ holds because the pullback of the canonical class is the canonical class.

In your two cases there is no reason for $(*)$ to be true, so an isomorphism of curves does not lift.